# Android : The app is to make it finish or stop working in background?

Tags: android, android-background

My Android app is very big and complex. Therefor the app use much memory space and CPU. So when user click the "home" or "back" button on Android device, I hope that the app finish completely.
Please someone help me. Appreciate that share sample code or link.

Comment: on you can release reference in onBackPressed() method of home activity

Answer (score 0):

You could call the `finish();` method in any activity either after starting the next activity, or in `onPause();` 
**example**: 
After starting activity B from activity A

```
startActivity(new Intent(A.this, B.class));
finish();
```

and to make sure activity does not stay in the background when pressing Home button you could call `finish();` inside your onPause();

```
@Override
protected void onPause(){
    finish();
}
```

Comment: In my app used many activities. According your sample code, when start new activity from main activity the app would be finished.

Comment: Not exactly, the finish(); only kills the activity, so if you call it from your MainActivity, the next activity will start but you won't be able to navigate back to your MainActivity, you could just NOT call it in the MainActivity if you want it to stay.